# how to detect when compiler emits an error

Tags: c++, perl, g++

To compile a `C++` project, I want to write a `perl` script to compile my program and see if the compilation went wrong or not. If the compiler gives any compilation error, I'll need to perform some other task.

The `perl` script will be something like this:

```
   @l1 =  `find . -name '*.c'`;
   @l2 =  `find . -name '*.cpp'`;
   @l3 =  `find . -name '*.cc'`;
   my $err;
   my $FLAGS = "-DNDEBUG"   
   push(@l , @l1, @l2, @l3);
   chomp(@l);
   foreach (@l) {
     print "processing file $_ ...";
     $err = `g++ $_ $FLAGS`;
     if($err == something) {
       #do the needful
     }
   }
```

so what should be **something**?

Comment: Ack!  It looks like you are trying to implement make.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: actually I'm doing a bit of code-refactoring in C++ program. so after refactoring i want to automate the compilation so that if there is an error revert back to the original file, otherwise continue refactoring the next program.

Comment: If it can be done using Make, I can try that also. Please give any reference to relevant resources. Thanks.

Comment: <refactor>; if make; then <increment file>; fi; <repeat>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check `$?` instead, after `g++...`.

**[perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)**

> `$?`
>
> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (`` ) command,
>   successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator.
>
> **The exit value of the subprocess is really `($?>> 8)`**

So you should check if `g++` returned `0` (success) or `non-zero`.

```
if ($? >> 8) {
    /* Error? */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IPC::System::Simple/IPC::Run3 make this easier